# How to screen a rectangle with a keyup event?

Tags: vb.net, forms

The sun is still above the horizon. With 7:43 from Baden Austria i try to mention my titel question with some additional example.
Following the Window10 environment build 19041.985 Visual Studio Community Version 4.8.04084,
the predfined Keys of a Logitech Deluxe 250 Keyboard are not altered with the visual basic method

```
    Sub Kein_Stress_beim_Essen(e As KeyEventArgs)
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Space
                Dim Kautchuj As Drawing.Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
                Kautchuj.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Color.PaleGreen, 2), 250, 150, 100, 50)
        End Select
    End Sub
```

.
To strengthen the sum for physical exercises, pull the sholder bladebones to the rising sun balance until pushing back without regret where i need them, the DrawRectangle is set with the form property CreateGraphics.
For more then one property i search, to use, the GDI+ objects that can be set to link a Me.KeyUp delegate with the event literature.
For my personal argument i use an additional cross to start and end a even, odd number disscusion.

I try to screen a rectangle through the case Keys.Space. While CreateGraphics is, literally, used for the aim of controls in visual basic with a rectangle object i can imagine a paint event and do not know if the key event can also be used for a object.

I have a search pattern to concatenate operators a not named function. It is not possible that everything is an object. Even with some energy exercises. To aim i fade the predefined color names to build an enum naming convention. Some dictionary brainstorm words are delegate, event eventargs, tupel, keys, select, property, method and instance.

I do not concider the possibility to make new fonts because an ime substitution is not an additional information for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. This seems like the result of a poor translation. If you're asking how to draw using GDI+, do it only on the `Paint` event. Call `Invalidate` to raise an event and specify the area to be repainted, then do the drawing in the `Paint` event handler or the overridden `OnPaint` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're asking how to draw boxes on the `KeyUp` event. In that case, here's a quick demo of how it should be done:

```vb
Private ReadOnly points As New List(Of Point)
Private ReadOnly rng As New Random

Private Const BOX_DIMENSION As Integer = 10

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Space
            'Draw a new box at a random location.
            Dim x = rng.Next(ClientSize.Width)
            Dim y = rng.Next(ClientSize.Height)

            points.Add(New Point(x, y))

            'Repaint just the area that will be occupied by the new box.
            Invalidate(New Rectangle(x, y, BOX_DIMENSION + 1, BOX_DIMENSION + 1))
        Case Keys.Escape
            'Erase all boxes.
            points.Clear()

            'Repaint the whole form.
            Invalidate()
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    'Draw a box at each location.
    For Each point In points
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, point.X, point.Y, BOX_DIMENSION, BOX_DIMENSION)
    Next
End Sub
```

As you can see, all the drawing is done in the `Paint` event handler. The `KeyUp` event handler updates the data that represents the drawing and then forces a repaint.

Comment: Maybe, the invalidation is to read from the rectangle paintevent. Maybe not! The instance of the structure rectangle as part of the screen, the method drawrectangle, is "ready" to be invalidated with the keyevent. Befor i copy and paste the above decoded form code, i need to know: is it possible to use only the rectangle structure instance without the invalidation context?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. The way I've shown is the right way to do it. Do it the way I've shown.

Comment: The above posted content makes my development easier. But i need also an example to learn why to use invalidate. Do i have to invalidate a frame or is it possible to start with a keyup event without invalidation?

Comment: You already have an example of why to use `Invalidate` because it's included in my code above. You store the data that represents the drawing in one or more fields. On the `Paint` event, you read the data from that field(s) and use it to do the drawing. When the drawing needs to change, you update in the data in the field(s) and call `Invalidate` to force a `Paint` event. Invalidate the smallest area possible to keep repainting to a minimum and only call `Invalidate` with no argument if the entire control has or may have changed.

Comment: To learn the invalidation "process" without specific geometry bindings i started replacing `Dim x,y = 200` through `Public Sub New() With Me .Size = New Point(600, 600) End With End Sub`